# floating point types: Does the order of operations with the same associativity matter for accuracy?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, c++20

Whenever I come accross an operation with FP-types, I ask myself if it makes sense to reorder them to keep maximum accuracy. Does it matter? Consider the following example I copied from my production code:

```
double duty = ch.calc_duty(ch.calc_output(time_curr)*modificator_*throttle_/100.0);
```

Now say `modificator_` and `throttle_` are both of type double, so is the result of `calc_output()`. Would I gain accuracy if I divided by 100.0 first? I heard that FP's are more accuate around 0 so I'm thinking it would make sense to keep them close to 0 for each successive FP operation.

```
double duty = ch.calc_duty(ch.calc_output(time_curr)/100.0*modificator_*throttle_);
```

I don't think that the compiler can help me with reordering because it has no information about the runtime properties of `modificator_` and `throttle_`. However, I know that modificator and throttle are in the range of [0-1] and calc_output() will return a percentual value from [0-100].

Comment: The answer to the question in the subject line is "often", if you consider addition and subtraction. For multiplication and division the answer is "sometimes", in particular when underflow to a subnormal number occurs in the course of some of the potential variants. For sanity in numerically sensitive computations, you would *not* want re-association of floating-point computation by compilers (this might require specific compiler switches, e.g. `-fp-model=strict`, to enforce).

Comment: Yes order matters. Multiplication and division will be done left to right, and could lead to different results depending on the order. Not only because of the normal rounding errors inherent in floating point operations, but also because of possible overflows (especially if any of the involved variables and returned values happen to be integers).

Comment: No, this doesn't matter. No idea where you heard that FP are more accurate around 0. They have the same amount of digits for mantissa and power regardless of the value. What you said would make sense for other representations of FP that currently aren't used in the field.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude order matters but it doesn't affect accuracy in his case. One will get different value but accuracy promises are the same.

Comment: @ALX23z So to sum up: The result value is different but both numbers will have the same accuracy over the whole operation? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @ALX23z: Re “No idea where you heard that FP are more accurate around 0”: Floating-point representations have more absolute precision at lower magnitudes. That is the whole point of floating-point: The point floats, allowing for finer representations with lower exponents and coarser representations with larger exponents. The relative precision remains similar throughout most of the range.

Comment: @ALX23z: Re “No, this doesn't matter”: It can matter, depending on the specific values involved. If some operands have fewer significant bits (lots of trailing zeros in the significands), multiplying them may have no rounding error, so it may be preferable to multiply them first, and there can be other complications, including underflow and overflow.

Comment: @ALX23z: Re “mantissa”: The preferred term is “significand.” “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. The fraction portion of a floating-point representation is a significand. Mantissas are logarithmic; adding to a mantissa multiplies the represented number. Significands are linear; adding to a significand adds to the represented number (scaled by the exponent).

Comment: @ALX23z: “One will get different value but accuracy promises are the same”: Different values have different accuracies unless they are equidistant from the ideal result on different sides.

Comment: Without more information, there may be little point in reordering `a*b*c/100.`. If you have information about certain properties of `a`, `b`, and `c`, there might be some point in reordering them. Given the limited ranges you state for `a`, `b`, and `c`, there is no hazard of underflow or underflow, so the only benefit I see would be if you happen to know that `a`, `b`, and/or `c` has a limited number of significant bits (e.g., if they originate with the `float` type instead of `double` or come from some A-to-D converter that produces a limited number of bits).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for clearing up that delicate topic! Another question: Does the literal 100.0 have infinitely many significant digits? If not would it not be wiser to state at the end (or add more significant digits like 100.00000)?

Comment: @glades: The significant digits of a number are, in a chosen base, those from its first non-zero digit to its last non-zero digit. In binary, one hundred is 1100100, so it has five significant digits, 11001. This is relevant because any number in range with 53 or fewer significant digits can be represented exactly in the format commonly used for `double`, IEEE-754 binary64. So we could multiply 100 by another number without many significant digits and get an exact result with no error. However, dividing by 100 will incur rounding error unless the numerator is a (scaled) multiple of 25.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That’s what’s relevant to storage, of course, although in general scientific usage certainly we can distinguish 10. from 10 as having 2 significant digits.

Comment: @DavisHerring What I've learned also is that 100 has 3 significant digits while 100.00 has 5. The post-digit 00 count as well because the first 100 could also mean 100.49 while this is not allowed in the second case.

Comment: @glades: Correct, but that notion of significance doesn’t affect the results of arithmetic (before any voluntary rounding).

Comment: @DavisHerring: It is about representation and format, not storage. All numbers with a number of significant digits, in the definition I gave, less than or equal to the number of digits in the significand of the floating-point format can be represented in the format, subject to exponent range. That means if any such number is the mathematical result of an operation, there is no need to round it to fit in the format. And that is the point here; numbers with few significant digits can be multiplied with no rounding error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That’s what I meant by “storage”: you can’t store 1+2^-(n+1), but you can store 1+2^-n.